# How does discord work on all platforms?

Tags: javascript, react-native, web, electron, cross-platform

Does discord work on mobile platform by use react native and work on desktop platform by use electronjs ?

Comment: Please be more clear on the issue.

Comment: I want to learn how I can build a application in all platforms like discord

Comment: Yeah. I mean, Discord won't use the same technology for each and every platform. You've got react-native which can help with iOS/Android, electron can help with windows/macOS, and react on the web. There is also react-native for windows & macOS (not sure how good they are yet), and also react-native for web. One thing is for sure, it's an insane amount of work to build a good app for one platform, so you'll have to invest a lot of time a lot of stuff.

Answer (score -1):

The creators of Discord had to make each app / website for each platform. If you want to make your app work on all platforms (similar to discord), you're going to have to create it for each platform, which can be very tedious.